# How to remove parenthesis using regex on Python?

Tags: python, regex

I have string like this:

```
Alex Jatt, (alex.jatt@domain.com)
```

amd I'm trying to extract only email address using regex like so:

```
p = re.search('\((.*?)\)', c)
```

but
    print p command prints *(alex.jatt@domain.com)*

How can I modify this regex to get rid of parenthesis?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`re.search` allows you to pull matched groups out of the regular expression match. In your case, you would want to use `p.group(1)` to extract the first parenthesized match, which should be the email in the regular expression you have.

Answer (score 3):

without `regex` solution:

```
>>> strs="Alex Jatt, (alex.jatt@domain.com)"
>>> strs.split(',')[1].strip().strip("()")
'alex.jatt@domain.com'
```

Answer (score 3):

With join also you can do it..

```
a= ''.join(c for c in a if c not in '()')
```

or with regex..

```
In[20]: import re

In[21]: name= re.sub('[()]', '', a)

In [22]: name
Out[22]: 'Alex Jatt, alex.jatt@domain.com'
```

Answer (score 2):

use a look ahead and a look behind to make sure that the parenthesis are there, but to prevent you from capturing them.

```
p = re.search('(?<=\().*?(?=\))', c)
```

or you could just access the capture group instead of the whole regex.

```
p = re.search('\((.*?)\)', c).group(1)
```

either way would work.

Answer (score 0):

I think you've been changing the code before pasting it in here.

If I do:

```
>>> import re
>>> c="Alex Jatt, (alex.jatt@domain.com)"
>>> p = re.search('\((.*?)\)', c)
>>> print p
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x10bd68af8>
```

You want to look at the groups:

```
>>> import re
>>> c="Alex Jatt, (alex.jatt@domain.com)"
>>> p = re.search('\((.*?)\)', c)
>>> print p.groups()[0]
alex.jatt@domain.com
```