# how can i delete "(",")"?

Tags: python, regex

how can i delete "("?
is it correct ? :

```
import re, sys
my_source = {}
list_of_words  = {}
text_we_need   = {}
dict_of_words  = {}
max_characters = 0
with open("my_source2.txt") as f:
    my_source = f.read()
p = re.compile(r'<a(.*?)</a>')
my_source = p.sub('<a></a>', my_source, re.DOTALL)
my_source = re.sub('<a>','',my_source)
my_source = re.sub('(','',my_source)
my_source = re.sub(')','',my_source)
```

why this code,doesn't work for '(' ??

Comment: Don't try to parse HTML with regexes. Use an HTML parser.

Comment: An editorial note: Asking "Why doesn't this work!?" without providing the error you get is not productive. Other than that, what do the python docs say about escaping special characters in regular expressions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`(` and `)` are special characters in a regex, as they are used for grouping. You need to escape the `(` and `)` using `\`.

```
my_source = re.sub('\(','',my_source)
my_source = re.sub('\)','',my_source)
```

Comment: Indeed, or another way of escaping it and avoiding two subs is to use `[()]` instead... But at a cursory glance, the OP is using the wrong approach for this job anyway...

Answer (score 0):

I looked around, and I found several similar questions.

1. [Python Strip multiple characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3900054/python-strip-multiple-characters)
2. [Regex How to remove symbols from a string Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/875968/how-to-remove-symbols-from-a-string-with-python)
3. [How to remove parenthesis using regex on Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11971696/how-to-remove-parenthesis-using-regex-on-python)

It appears that the "double-quotations" should work instead of 'single-quotations'.

Comment: how can i delete '*' , '\' , '#' , ... from the text ?

Answer (score 0):

Posted this on your other thread as well:

Don't use a regex for something this simple.  Use translate:

[Python string doc](http://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html)

```
>>> str = "This is a (string) (example)..."
>>> str.translate(None, "()")
'This is a string example...'
>>>
```